# Email From Template addons php tag not working

Tags: email

when We have add code like this in email form template then php code not working.

code like this.

```
{exp:email_from_template to="mailid" from="mailid"  echo="off" mailtype="html" }
     //php code $test= "hi"; 

    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel" dynamic="no" disable="pagination|member_data|categories" }

         //php code  echo $test; 

    {/exp:channel:entries}

 {/exp:email_form_template}
```

above code echo test not display , We have already set allow php ="yes" parse order="output" for template.

let me know any idea for this.

Thanks,
Piyush

Comment: Does your `email_from_template` module actually return anything?

Comment: I assume the code posted above is not the actual code? Does non-PHP data get parsed correctly?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Since I cannot comment on the original post, how can I ask for clarification?

Answer (score 2):

```
php ="yes" parse order="output"
```

it is mean that php code is will be executed **after** all tags. Include fact that it will executed **after** email will sent.

You need to change it to **input** if you want to see php code results in your email.

*as solution* - put you code with php into embed template with parse order ="output"